# Django app with other apps as dependencies

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-apps

Imagine you create a reusable django app 'A' which depends on another reusable django app 'B'. Now if I want to use an app 'A' I have to add not only 'A' but also 'B' in INSTALLED_APPS? How do I add only 'A' without explicitly adding 'B' too?

Comment: If app A depends on app B, then the general answer is "you can't". To give a more specific answer you'd need to be more specific about how your apps are dependent on each other.

Comment: 'B' has models that 'A' uses.

Comment: The answer then is that you need to install both apps.

Comment: ... by both of them adding to INSTALLED_APPS list ?

Comment: Yes, you have to add them both.